# immutableList but still able to modify elements in the list

Tags: java, list, immutability

I am using com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList to not allow any modification to the element in the list. The code looks like below but the assertion failed.
MyObj doesn't override clone method, is that why it fails?

```
    MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
    myObj.setName("foo");
    Collection<MyObj> sets = new HashSet<MyObj>();
    sets.add(myObj);
    ImmutableCollection<MyObj> immutableSets = ImmutableList.copyOf(sets);
    for(MyObj obj : immutableSets){
        obj.setName("var");
    }
    assertTrue(myObj.getName()=="foo");
```

Comment: Don't you have to do something like "getName().Equals("foo")) ?

Comment: The `List` is immutable, not the elements of the `List`.

Comment: Also, don't use `==` to check for `String` equality.

Comment: The best way for your comparison is: assertEquals("foo", myObj.getName());

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are modifying an object inside the list, not the list itself.

If you want to avoid such modifications, your immutable list must contain immutable objects.